# Get retrived records count from OleDbDataReader in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, oledbdatareader

I want to get the retrived records count from the `OleDbDataReader` in *C#* ?

```
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Table_Name" ;                   
    dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(strQuery, dbConnection);
    dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
    //Now how to get RowCount from the Table after this.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For more detail : [Get row count by 'ExecuteScalar'](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/GetrowcountbyExecuteScalar.htm)

Make use of `ExecuteSclar()` rather than going for `read` function.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM " + Table_Name, conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        int total = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i am using sqlBulkCopy to copy from MS Access to SQL DB . now i want to know that how many rows have been copied how i can achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

You could change the query to:

```
strQuery = "SELECT count(*) as RowCount, * FROM " + Table_Name;
```

That would allow you to retrieve the rowcount like:

```
dbReader.Read();
var rowCount = (int)dbRead["RowCount"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, but there are likely better ways:

```
int i = 0;
While (dbReader.Read()){
   i++;
}
```

Comment: it's a way that works, and doesn't modify the OP's query. If the OP actually needs data from records, then even better since processing can be done in the `While` loop

Comment: but i admit it's not the most efficient to loop over the rows just to get the count